# Exception thrown when comparing property of custom class with variable

Tags: vb.net, linq, comparison

I have the following class:

```
Public Class Row

    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByRef lookupTable As LookupTable)
        myLookupTable = lookupTable
    End Sub

    Private myLookupTable As LookupTable

    <XmlAttribute("value")> _
    Public Property Value As Double

    <XmlArray("values")> _
    <XmlArrayItem("value")> _
    Public Property Values As List(Of Double)

    <XmlIgnore> _
    Public ReadOnly Property LookupTable As LookupTable
        Get
            Return myLookupTable
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

And I am trying to do the following:

```
Dim yIndexBelow As Integer = Rows.IndexOf(Rows.Where(Function(row) row.Value <= yVal).Max())
Dim yIndexAbove As Integer = Rows.IndexOf(Rows.Where(Function(row) row.Value >= yVal).Min())
Dim yProportion As Double = (yVal - Rows(yIndexBelow).Value) / (Rows(yIndexAbove).Value - Rows(yIndexBelow).Value)
```

On the *second* line *only*, an Exception is thrown: `At least one object must implement IComparable.` Uhhhhh.... What?

Since when does `Double`not implement IComparable? Obvisously it does.

What's more; why is it only failing on the *second* line?

Any ideas?.

**P.S.**
 `yVal` *is* set, in case you were wondering.

Answer (score 2):

To prove your point, this class would suffice

```
Public Class Row
    Public Property Value As Double
End Class
```

The solution, as you mentioned, is to implement IComparable. See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/320727

```
Public Class Row
    Implements IComparable(Of Row)

    Public Property Value As Double

    Public Function CompareTo(other As Row) As Integer _
        Implements IComparable(Of Row).CompareTo
        Return If(Me.Value > other.Value, 1, -1)
    End Function

End Class
```

The test case only requires the index finding portion. Here is a good example. This should be tested with both versions of `Row` above. One will see that when `Row` doesn't implement IComparable, the first portion works since there is only one element, as you pointed out, but the second portion does not. Simply, LINQ's Max function is just short-circuiting the comparison because there is only one element.

```
Sub Main()
    Dim yVal As Double = 6.7
    Dim yIndexBelow As Integer
    Dim yIndexAbove As Integer

    Dim rows As New List(Of Row)()

    rows.Add(New Row() With {.Value = 5})

    yIndexBelow = rows.IndexOf(rows.Where(Function(row) row.Value <= yVal).Max())
    yIndexAbove = rows.IndexOf(rows.Where(Function(row) row.Value >= yVal).Min())
    Console.WriteLine("Rows: {0}",
                      String.Join(", ", rows.Select(Of Double)(Function(r) r.Value)))
    Console.WriteLine("Index below {0}: {1}",
                      yIndexBelow, If(yIndexBelow = -1, "N/A", rows(yIndexBelow).Value))
    Console.WriteLine("Index above {0}: {1}",
                      yIndexAbove, If(yIndexAbove = -1, "N/A", rows(yIndexAbove).Value))

    rows.Add(New Row() With {.Value = 6})
    rows.Add(New Row() With {.Value = 2})
    rows.Add(New Row() With {.Value = 10})
    rows.Add(New Row() With {.Value = -6})
    rows.Add(New Row() With {.Value = 12})
    rows.Add(New Row() With {.Value = 1})

    yIndexBelow = rows.IndexOf(rows.Where(Function(row) row.Value <= yVal).Max())
    yIndexAbove = rows.IndexOf(rows.Where(Function(row) row.Value >= yVal).Min())

    Console.WriteLine("Rows: {0}",
                      String.Join(", ", rows.Select(Of Double)(Function(r) r.Value)))
    Console.WriteLine("Index below {0}: {1}",
                      yIndexBelow, If(yIndexBelow = -1, "N/A", rows(yIndexBelow).Value))
    Console.WriteLine("Index above {0}: {1}",
                      yIndexAbove, If(yIndexAbove = -1, "N/A", rows(yIndexAbove).Value))

End Sub
```

Output when `Row` implements IComparable:

> yVal: 6.7
>   
> Rows: 5
>   
> Index below 0: 5
>   
> Index above -1: N/A
>   
> Rows: 5, 6, 2, 10, -6, 12, 1
>   
> Index below 1: 6
>   
> Index above 3: 10

This is interesting, and I checked Google / SO / MSDN for any mention of this behavior, but couldn't find any. Logically, it makes sense, but can lead to points of confusion.

Comment: Very detailed! This will be very useful for anyone having the same problem. +1 for creating a test case. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is because `Min()` and `Max()` are attempting to compare the `Row`s which do not implement `IComparable`. The reason the first line works is because `Max()` has only one possible row to return (in my test case).

So the moral of this story is: Compare things that are comparable (duh!) *and* `Max()` and `Min()` will not complain about comparability if there is only one object in the collection.